# How to recognize and make hyper links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

How I can use Jquery to find `http://` or `www.` and ends with `.com`, `.org`, `.edu` store that as a variable and wrap it in like:

```
<a href="variable">  <a/>
```

I have a textarea and when people put in links, I would like to then make them into hyperlinks once they are posted.

Comment: If you don't want to do it until they are posted, you want to do this with server-side code rather than with jquery.  If you're using JS to create a preview of the post before submission, then using jquery would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say the text area contains,

```
http://site1.com/uri/
http://site2.net/uri
http://site3.org/uri
http://site4.co.uk/uri
http://site5.ws/uri
```

The first thing i would do is bind an even for keyup on the textarea

```
$('#addLinks').bind('keyup',function(){
    var _data = $(this).val();
    //Then i would try and split the spaces and carriages 
    _array = _data.split('\n|\r\n|\s|,'); //Split by returns,new lines,spaces,commas.
    var _regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
    $(_array).each(function(value){
       //Now i will check the URL is valid
       if(_regex.test(value))
       {
           //Valid URL so i will then append it to the links container
           //Here you can do e
           $('<a></a>').attr('href',value).val(value).appendTo('.linksContainer');
       }
    })
});
```

Something along them lines!

Regex borrowed from: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/452

Answer (score 0):

---

roll your own way:

```
var foo = $('textarea selector').val();
```

then use a regular expression to get what you want.  then stick it back into the textarea

```
$('textarea selector').val('http://thenewlink');
```

easy plugin way:

[7 jQuery Plugins to Manipulate TEXTAREAs](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/7-jquery-plugins-to-manipulate-textareas/)